# how to create python empty dataframe where df.empty results in True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, is-empty

How can I create an empty dataframe in python such that the test `df.empty` results `True`?

I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((1, 1)))
```

and `df.empty` results in `False`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest is `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()   

df.empty
# True
```

If you want create a data frame of specify number of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])

df.empty
# True
```

Besides, an array of shape *(1, 1)* is not empty (it has one row), which is the reason you get *empty = False*, in order to create an empty array, it needs to be of shape *(0, n)*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 3)))

df.empty
# True
```

Comment: so simple that I overlooked it :-)